# JDBC connection to Oracle server from Spark

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, jdbc

When a connection to Oracle server is made from Spark cluster, would the JDBC connection to Oracle server would be established from the node/box where the code is being executed or would it be executed from data nodes? In later case, whether the drivers need to be installed on all data nodes for it to be connecting to Oracle server.

Answer (score 1):

> When a connection to Oracle server is made from Spark cluster, would the JDBC connection to Oracle server would be established from the node/box where the code is being executed or would it be executed from data nodes?

Data is always loaded from the executor nodes. However driver node needs an access to the database as well, to be able fetch metadata.

> In later case, whether the drivers need to be installed on all data nodes for it to be connecting to Oracle server.

Yes. Driver has to be present on each node used by the Spark application. This can done by:

- Having required jars on the classpath of each node.
- Using `spark.jars` to distribute jars on the runtime
- Using `spark.jars.packages` to fetch jars using Maven coordinates.